# Check the update date of a file with FTP functions?

Tags: php, ftp

I need to get some files on a remote server, by ftp-get.

However, the files to download are weigth (more than 50MB).

So, I didn't download the file if the last update has not change (so, the file 'toto.xml' is the same on the two servers).

It's possible to do it with FTP functions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ftp_mdtm() gets the last modified time for a remote file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mdtm.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mdtm.php